# Howto make MCrypt and PHP work together on CentOS

Tags: php, centos, php5

I've installed mcrypt on CentOS ( via yum ), but when I try to do a dl() call in A), I get the message in B).

- A) dl( mcrypt.so ) or die('The Mcrypt
  module could not be loaded ['.
  $prefix . 'mcrypt.' .
  PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX .']');
- B) The
  Mcrypt module could not be loaded [
  mcrypt.so ]

Now, I know that yum has installed mcrypt, but I don't know the location it has put it in. Can I find that out? More importantly, how can I get the latest installed mcrypt working with my PHP system. Many threads suggest you recompile PHP ( ex: http://forums.theplanet.com/index.php?showtopic=26527 ), but I don't know how to do this with CentOS. I've also played with my library paths to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Setup**

- CentOS:  Linux localhost.localdomain
  2.6.18-128.1.6.el5 #1 SMP Wed Apr 1 09:10:25 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64
  x86_64 GNU/Linux
- mcrypt:
  mcrypt-2.6.8-1.el5.x86_64
- PHP:  php-5.1.6-23.2.el5_3.x86_64

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the packages libmcrypt and php-mcrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure that the line

extension=php_mcrypt.dll

in your php.ini file is not commented out (preceeded with a ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I had issues installing the mcrypt module on Centos 5.5 with PHP 5.2.9., what i found is that when I finally found an x64 version of php-mcrypt it installed the mcrypt.so file in /usr/lib64/php/modules/ folder, hover my PHP.ini file was looking in a completely different place for it's modules /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/ so a copied the mycrpt folder to the /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/ folder and added the line extension="mcrypt.so" to the top of my php.ini folder saved it and restarted apache and it worked